# Error in deserializing a column of List<UserType> from cassandra query output in datastax Driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Deserialize method:

```
override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer, protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): UserType = {

Option(bytes) match {
  case Some(value) if value.remaining == 0 =>
    throw new Exception(s"Cannot Deserialize empty bytes Array!!!! $this.getClass")
  case Some(value) =>
    val byteArray = new Array[Byte](bytes.remaining)
    bytes.duplicate.get(byteArray)
    objectMapper.readValue[java.util.List[UserType]] (byteArray, classOf[java.util.List[UserType]] ).get(0)
  case _ =>
    null
}
```

}

I am able to read the bytes of the column via custom codec. But, its deserialization is failing with error

> java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x314c5555
>   (above 0x0010ffff) at char #3, byte #15)  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:195)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:158)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:250)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2354)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:672)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4340)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3266)

How can i deserialize the bytes received ?

Type definition in cassandra is

```
CREATE TYPE canada_catalog.UserType (id text, flag1 BOOLEAN,flag2 BOOLEAN);
```

Cassandra Column is of type `frozen<list<frozen<usertype>>>`

Comment: why not simply use object mapper from java driver?